# PHPUnit and testing CRUD methods

Tags: php, testing, netbeans, mysqli, phpunit

I've got PHP DAO classes with CRUD methods (inserting, reading, updating, and deleting DB records). In many of PHPUnit testing examples on internet there's a test with simple sum($a,$b) method where one can easily define input and expected output for PHPUnit testing (1+1 should return 2).

How to test CRUD methods? Sometimes I change database model, sometimes I do refactor/change my code. My question here is how to define assertions for insert, select, update, and delete methods of my class? I want to test with PHPUnit weather my CRUD methods work as expected?

Comment: Mocks for the database interaction will test that your modified code works, as you can validate what you are building (the actual query, etc...) without the need to interact with the database. If your code returns certain data on a get, the Mock has that hard coded so your program continues as it would.  Once this code works, there is a DBUnit class that can help integrate the database tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this for my database tests (when mocking does not do the trick - at some point you want to actually test the database interaction) - https://github.com/malteriesch/test-db-acle

An alternative (quite popular one) is DBUnit: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit

Disclaimer: I wrote test-db-acle so I tend to gravitate towards that one :)